Why Acid chloride does not react with tertiary amine? (Looking for a suitable reason)
When acid chloride is reacted with a tertiary amine, it basically does not show any reaction. I cannot find a satisfactory reason to this. Everywhere on the internet says, because there's no replaceable hydrogen, but why do we need any replaceable hydrogen at all? The $\ce{Cl-}$ ion which leaves at first, why wouldn't it perform $\mathrm{S_N2}$ on one of the alkyl groups of positively charged $\ce{(NR_3)+}$ and hence form $\ce{RCl}$ as one of the products.


sorry if the question is silly, I'm not very good at chemistry

Well, maybe not silly, but not great too. Cl isn't a good nucleophile and breaking this bond would be way more difficult.

That is a reasonable mechanism that does not seem to happen. A close examination should give a kinetic or bond strength explanation. Once the bottleneck is found it might be possible to circumvent it and a new reaction named after you is born. It is not a silly question but a good question that could incite research especially if that might be a useful reaction to convert a tertiary amine to a secondary amine

This appears relevant but I can only read the abstract  https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040402001828817

I would guess that the tertiary amine is bulky enough that addition into the carbonyl is slow.

@jimchmst Except it's impossible to make it like that? There's no way something substitutes alkyl instead of binding again to carbonyl.

This isn’t an unreasonable mechanism, but the chloride ion is a notably weak nucleophile, and in this case likely too weak to produce and significant amount of the amide.

Some acyl chlorides do react with triethylamine but by a different mechanism.

This is certainly an interesting question which got me thinking but there are a few things wrong here.
Nitrogen breaks it bonds with hydrogen to remove the negative charge - this is known as deprotonation. But it can't do that at all with a Carbon in a R group - deprotonation is the loss of proton to stabilize charge but R groups aren't good leaving groups as when the R group breaks away to form R+ carbocation, it will be too unstable and C won't be able to stabilize the positive charge on it. This is why acids often donate hydrogen ions - they would never be able to donate R group or Carbon atoms
Linking to this, R groups also form a much stronger bond with nitrogen atom and when chloride ion as a nucleophille attacks, the Bond between R and N and the fact that R groups are horrible leaving groups means that the chloride ion won't form R - Cl with chloride ion
Hence the reaction doesn't occur otherwise you would produce an unstable N+ - C intermediate.
However as mentioned in the comments, there is research done on this area because some more complicated acyl chlorides are able to react with tertiary amines like triethylamine.
I also would  imagine an N - substitued amide with 2 R groups would be unstable/not exist but I am not sure about whether it will be unstable
